# Camel route testing

Tags: unit-testing, apache-camel

I need to write unit test cases for some camel routes using (Version 1.6)

Can anyone please suggest if it is possible to mock components(processor and idempotentConsumer) inside the route? If yes, please suggest the approach.

Below is the route snippet

```
    from("direct:someuri").process(someClassObject).
    idempotentConsumer(header("someHeadername"),socratesMessageIdRepository(bean(JpaTemplate.class)))./*process(exceptionProcessor)*/
    to(someQueues);
```

Answer (score 3):

Camel has a great framework for testing and mocking.

There are a lot of topics on the subject and I recommend you to start reading here: http://camel.apache.org/mock and here http://camel.apache.org/testing.html

Note that the Camel source is full of test cases that you could study some to get inspiration how to testing/mocking. Ex. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/processor/IdempotentConsumerTest.java

If you simply want to mock a processor, you could do so using the bean component instead and call it by reference.

```
from("foo").bean("myBean").to("bar);
```

If you are using spring you can simply just inject a mock version of your processor and name it myBean. Even without spring, Camel has a registry you can bind your mock version in, instead of the real one.